# Local SQL Server database is not connected

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework version 6.0. I want to connect to a local SQL Server database. I am using the following connection string. But I cannot connect to the database. Please give me the solution.

```
<add name="dbecommerceEntities"         
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.dbEcommerceMode.csdl|res://*/Models.dbEcommerceMode.ssdl|res://*/Models.dbEcommerceMode.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;Integrated Security=False;Initial Catalog=dbecommerce;User ID=qaws;Password=1q2w!A@S;Connect Timeout=30000;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096;App=EntityFramework&quot;"   />
```

Comment: There is no connection string shown in your post.

Comment: Also: what error (if any) do you get when trying to connect? And **how** are you trying to connect? (please show your code!)

Comment: http://www.akhayaecs.in/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 > 5ms]

Comment: the file was not uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Check the usual suspects:

- `data source=localhost` : this means, there **must be** a default, unnamed SQL Server instance on your local computer - is there? Or did you install SQL Server **Express** in default mode? Then you'd have to use `data source=(local)\SQLExpress` instead
- `User ID=qaws;Password=1q2w!A@S` : do you have this user ID and this password as a **login** on your SQL Server instance?
- `Initial Catalog=dbecommerce;`: does that database exist on that SQL Server instance? Is the login from above defined as a **user** in this database, and has the permissions needed to do work?

Comment: on my computer it is working fine. But when i am hostng the project in a domain it is not showing any data. please give me suggestion.

Comment: @user1413974: as I said - you need to check things like machine name, edition of SQL Server installed etc. - I don't have access to your system - I really cannot tell you more than these points to check. But **you** need to do the checking....

Comment: my connection string was correct. one of the file was not uploaded to the server. now it is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

my connection string was correct. one of the file was not uploaded to the server. now it is working correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I do to test connection to database:

1. Create a .txt file somewhere in your computer.
2. Rename the file to .udl
3. Accept the change extension question and double click the file to open.
4. In your case, in the first tab, select SQL server and in the second tab, fill in the required fields.
5. Test the connection and if unsuccessful, it will provide you an error.
6. If successful, close the dialog and open the .udl file with notepad, you can see the connection string in the second line after ";" (the first semicolon)

HTH

Comment: my connection string was correct. one of the file was not uploaded to the server. now it is working correctly.